# Windows Computer Vision API - Image Format Invalid for Image In Binary - Java

Tags: java, azure, image-processing, computer-vision

I am facing an issue with Windows Computer Vision API. If I send a request with contentType = application/json and image URL in JSON request body things work fine but on sending a binary image(base 64 encoded) with contentType = application/octet-stream it gives me ImageFormatInvalid in the response.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Code:

```
final String binaryData = "data:image/jpeg;base64, /9............
ByteArrayEntity requestEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(binaryData.getBytes(),
ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

request.setEntity(requestEntity);            
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);            
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Response: InvalidImageFormat

Comment: Not sure without seeing all the code, but I found in C# I had to strip out the "data:image/jpeg;base64, " It is in C# but here is my working example, might help

Comment: @jimpaine 
Can you share the link to your working example?

Comment: Sorry, thought I had https://github.com/JimPaine/emotion-checker/blob/master/src/ImageProcessor/Function.cs

Comment: For quick reference see the method that starts at line 143

Comment: Hey @jimpaine,
Thank you for sharing :)
I have a similar thing done in java here, but for some reason, it is not working

Comment: Are you able to use something like Fiddler to capture the raw message that is being sent to the vision api? Also how are you generating the base64 string of the image? Any chance you could update with some more of the code?

Comment: Thank you @jimpaine
It worked. Updated changes below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was generating the binary incorrectly.
Worked when made changes as below:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decodeBase64(binaryData);
ByteArrayEntity requestEntity = new 
ByteArrayEntity(decodedString,ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
request.setEntity(requestEntity);
```